# Get caret position in a CKEditor

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor

I have a CKEditor in my template (unfortunately it is not my decision to use something else over this) of which I need to insert a pre-determined string into the existing text in the body at the current caret position. I cannot find a good way to obtain the position and any other support for this issue is scarce.

Does anyone know a way this this is possible?

**Component**

```
template = new Template() // eventually gets set
@ViewChild("cke-editor-name") editor: ElementRef;
insertText(string) {
    var caretPos = ???;
    template.BodyHtml = template.BodyHtml.substr(0, caretPos) + string + template.BodyHtml.substr(caretPos, string.length());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way that works well for me on every browser.

```
getCaretPos(){
    let sel = window.getSelection();
    let range;
    if (typeof document.caretPositionFromPoint !== "undefined") {
      var e = sel
        .getRangeAt(0)
        .cloneRange()
        .getBoundingClientRect()[0];
      range = document.caretPositionFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    } else if (sel && sel.rangeCount > 0) {
      range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
    }
    if (!range) return;
    var caretPos = range.startOffset;
    return caretPos;
}
```