# Is it possible to get Caret Position in CKEditor ? angular - javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor

I'm new to CKEditor, what I'm trying to do is to get the caret position in CKEditor element, to insert an additional text in that position.

I found this similar questions but that's not what I'm looking for: 
[Get caret position in a CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56083975/get-caret-position-in-a-ckeditor)

What I'm looking for is how to locate the text's position in the html that the CKEditor returns.

My code :

**HTML:**

```
  <div class="document-editor">
     <div class="document-editor__toolbar"></div>
         <div class="document-editor__editable-container" fusePerfectScrollbar>
             <div class="document-editor__editable" (click)="getSelected(editableArea)" #editableArea>
                  <p>The initial editor data.</p>
             </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

**TS:**

```
initEditor(language: any) {
    DecoupledEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('.document-editor__editable')
        )
        .then(newEditor => {
            const toolbarContainer = document.querySelector('.document-editor__toolbar');
            toolbarContainer.appendChild(newEditor.ui.view.toolbar.element);
            this.editor = newEditor;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
}
```

**What i tried to do ?**

I tried getting it using `window.getSelection().anchorOffset` and it is returning the position of the cursor in the current `div` , so for example if I try to color a part of the text in green, and then I click on it, it returns the position in the green text not in the whole content.

Does anyone know if it is possible? and how to do it?

Comment: For example, get the current position and then insert some text there?

Comment: how to insert it there ? , you can only get/set data from/to ckeditor , it returns an html code , not a pure text.

Comment: Did you look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61728192/)?

Comment: If you haven't seen already, you could also refer here: https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/CKEditor-3.x/Get-caret-position

Comment: i don't want to replace the text , i want to add a text in the caret position

Comment: about the second one , i already tried it and it's not working

Comment: @AymenTAGHLISSIA: The code in that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61728192/7670262) is already doing that. And, from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61971265/7670262), if you comment/remove the line `editor.execute('selectAll');` then it should work for your scenario as well i.e. insertion/addition of text where the cursor/caret is. Good luck!